# Onsubmit not executing function when it returns true

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form,

```
<form id="collabAccess"  onsubmit="return accessBox.submitCollabForm()" >
```

which runs accessBox.submitCollabForm() on submit.

The code for submitCollabForm is:

```
function submitCollabForm() {
    console.log('in submitcollabform');
    var valid = validateEmails();
    console.log(valid);
    if (valid == false) {
        $('#email').addClass('error');
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass('hidden');
        return false;
    } else {
        postCollaborators();
        console.log('in valid email');
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, whenever the variable valid is true, it appears that submitCollabForm is not actually running the else statement, as no console log statements are being output.  I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding how onsubmit works, or if something is wrong in my code.   Is the else statement actually being executed?

The postcollaborators() function:

```
postCollaborators = function() {
    baseURL = "";
    binId = "xyz";
    var pubaccess = $('#pubacc').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var emailval = email.split(',');
    var emaildata = "";
    var useraccess = $('#collabaccess').val();
    var access='';
    if (useraccess === 'Can Read') {
        access="Read";
    }
    else if (useraccess === 'Can Write') {
        access="Write";
    }
    else if (useraccess === 'Can Read & Write'){
        access="ReadWrite";
    }
    else {
        access="Administrator";
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < emailval.length; i++) {
        emailval[i] =  emailval[i].trim();

        emaildata += (emailval[i] + "=" + access +"?");
    }

    var bindata = "Bin="+binId + "?";
    var datastring = baseURL +"?" + bindata + emaildata + alldata;
```

Comment: are you sure that submitCollabForm() is inside the accessBox's object?

Comment: what is printed when you use console.log(valid)??@Mary

Comment: I'm positive the submitCollabForm() is inside accessBox, because when the email is not valid, the error message p ops up like it should.

Comment: And when valid is false, console.log(valid) outputs false, just as it should, but when valid is true, there is no output.

Comment: It appears to me that some code in `postCollaborators()` is preventing the remainder of the code in the else statement from being executed.  Look there, or post the code for the `postCollaborators()` function and I can help more.

Comment: I can add the code for postCollaborators(), but I'm not sure how it would stop the console.log(valid) statement, since that occurs before postCollaborators() is ever called.

Comment: @HowardRenollet did you notice anything wrong with the postCollaborators() code?